# Why is my Wordpress Post Loop not working?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, css, loops

Okay, I am trying run the wordpress post loop to print out the post titles and content using `the_title()` and `the_content()`. But It is not printing out the posts on the page?

Any ideas?

**index.php**

```
        <div class="blog-container">
        <!--  The POST LOOP -->
        <?php
        if(have_posts()) :
            while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; ?>

            <?php else : 
                echo '<p>No content found</p>';

            endif; 

        ?>

    </div>
```

**EDIT** Okay, I'm getting ONLY THE content printed out not the post titles, here is an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDCT7.jpg.

**EDIT 2** Inside wordpress admin post should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnzAZ.jpg

Comment: What happens if you add `global $wp_query; var_dump($wp_query); die;` before you start your loop. Are there any posts listed in the query object?

Comment: Looks good to me. Maybe you are on a page where no posts exists? You could enable the query log.

Comment: You may or may not want to use `<pre>` tags around that to better format the output.

Comment: Okay, I'm getting ONLY THE content printed out not the post titles, here is an image: http://imgur.com/a/DiBqG

Comment: please share your website link

Comment: Unfortunately its on a local xampp server atm

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the query and use the Wordpress build in functions in the wrong way. Here is the correction.

```
<?php
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query(  );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
echo '<ul>';
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
} else {
// no posts found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code for fetch post data

```
 <?php
    $post_args=array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'post_status'              => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page'           => -1,
        'orderby'                  => 'date',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',

    );

    $post_my_query = null;
    $post_my_query = new WP_Query($post_args);

    if( $post_my_query->have_posts() ) 
    {
        while ($post_my_query->have_posts()) : $post_my_query->the_post(); 
        ?>
        <h2><?php echo get_the_title( $post_my_query->ID );?></h2>
        <?php
             echo get_the_content( $post_my_query->ID );
          endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query($post_my_query);
?>
```

Comment: Pasted this in index.php, getting the content only, which I already have working

Comment: then what is issue? please describe more. i think it is issue in reset data